# CMultiFileUpload not show data in edit got in yii

Tags: yii, cmultifileupload

I am uploading multiple files in Yii with the help of `CMultiFileUpload` and this is the code:

```
$this->widget('CMultiFileUpload', array(
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'file',
    'accept' => 'jpg|gif|png|pdf',
    'options' => array(),
    'denied' => 'File is not allowed',
    'max' => 10
));
```

It worked in file upload but didn't show any data in edit form.